# How to show more than one address on same Markers on Google Map in Android

Tags: android

I am doing Google Map base app, In that i show the marker on map(latitude and longitude  taken from XML). On clicking the marker it display the Name and Address of that marker on one custom linear layout(pop-up like). On that layout there is two button close(close the pop-up) and next(which go to next activity). My problem is When on single marker(latitude and longitude  is same) there is a two Name and address come from XML then there is show only one name and address(which is last one).
         Is there any solution for this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what your using so I will assume you must be using ItemizedOverlay with OverlayItem. To do anything outside of the normal OverlayItem behavior you will have to extend  OverlayItem. OverlayItem has a .setMarker and .getMarker to start with.

If you're using MyLocationOverlay you may need to move to ItemizedOverlay as MyLocationOverlay extends OVerlay which will not have the mechanics to allow you to do what you're asking above.

Comment: Hye thanks for your suggestion, I solve this problem by using ItemizedOverlay.